# Where are activerecord object APIs located?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm looking at some ruby code in rails, which looks like:

```
user.jobs.order('created_at').not_closed.page(5)
```

In ActiveRecord::Base, I don't see any any "not_closed", "page", or "order" methods in the API.  What possible places can these methods originate?

Comment: +1 for trying to learn to fish rather than only asking for a fish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`order` is a core ActiveRecord method.

`not_closed` most likely, should be in the Job model (apps/models/job.rb).

`page` could be in the Jobs model, or in an external gem/plugin (probably pagination related).

Comment: not_closed is probably declared with named_scope if that helps.

Comment: +1 order, not_closed would need to be in the `Job` model, or whatever it is that defines the `jobs` association's objects, and `page` comes from the Kaminari gem.

Comment: Where can I get a list of "core" ActiveRecord methods?  After opening up base.rb I can see the includes, but it would be nice if there was some API doc that just listed all the stuff I could call.

Comment: @Frank, check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database